# Return Correct JSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I've created a recursive function to return hierarchal json

The output:

```
"[{""ID"" : 1, ""PARENT_ID"" : null, ""NAME"" : ""x"", ""CHILD"" : ""[{\""ID\"" : 2, \""PARENT_ID\"" : 1, \""NAME\"" : \""y\"", \""CHILD\"" : \""[{\\\""ID\\\"" : 3, \\\""PARENT_ID\\\"" : 2, \\\""NAME\\\"" : \\\""z\\\"", \\\""CHILD\\\"" : null}]\""}]""}]"
```

how to return it as JSON not string

Thanks on advance
;

```
CREATE TABLE HIERARCHAL_JSON
(ID   INT,
 PARENT_ID  INT,
 NAME   VARCHAR(100));
 
 INSERT INTO HIERARCHAL_JSON VALUES(1, NULL, 'x');
 INSERT INTO HIERARCHAL_JSON VALUES(2, 1, 'y');
 INSERT INTO HIERARCHAL_JSON VALUES(3, 2, 'z');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HIERARCHAL_JSON_FN ( P_id bigint) RETURNS varchar AS $body$
DECLARE

   RESULT text;

BEGIN
   SELECT
      json_agg(
          json_build_object(
              'ID'       , ID,
              'PARENT_ID'  , PARENT_ID,
              'NAME'  , NAME,
              'CHILD'    , public.HIERARCHAL_JSON_FN(CAST(id AS bigint))
      ))
    INTO STRICT RESULT
    FROM HIERARCHAL_JSON
    WHERE coalesce(PARENT_ID, 0) = coalesce(P_id, 0);
    RETURN RESULT;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

Comment: You are returning a string when you do `RETURN RESULT` as `RESULT` is defined as `text1. Essentially you are doing `select pg_typeof(json_agg(json_build_object('ID', id, 'Parent ID', parent_id))::text) from hierarchal_json ; text` The `pg_typeof() shows you what the Postgres type is for the result.

Comment: uh don't use `RETURNS varchar` if you want `RETURNS json`?! (Same for the `RESULT text` variable)